# What is the difference between rbenv 2.3.0 and 2.3.0-dev?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-elcapitan, rbenv

When I run `$ rbenv install --list` at the command line I get a list of version c/w extensions. Is there a difference btw `2.3.0` and `2.3.0-dev`?

Answer (score 0):

They are different. 2.3.0 is the version of ruby 2.3 that was released towards the end of 2015.

ruby-2.3.0-dev is something that was built from the state of the ruby source repository at a certain point in time. It could be anything from the point at which development started on ruby 2.3.0 up until right now. If you install it now then you'll get ruby 2.3.0 plus the latest commits on the ruby 2_3 branch.

You can see how the version are defined by looking at the ruby-build repo, e.g. [2.3.0-dev](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/blob/master/share/ruby-build/2.3.0-dev)